# docker node image, npm start no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-machine, boot2docker

I pulled node image. Now I am trying run container with mounted volume. My files (ExpressSite) are in "c:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/ExpressSite"

```
Milosz@DESKTOP-TN8ARMD MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/ExpressSite
$ docker run -p 8080:3000 -v "$(pwd)":/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
    npm ERR! path /var/www/package.json
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-16T15_06_09_756Z-debug.log
```

I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows. "/var/www" directory exists (c:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/ExpressSite/var/www)

Comment: Are you sure your directory is mounted correctly and /var/www/package.json exists?

Comment: "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/ExpressSite",
                "Destination": "/var/www",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against the wall, faced the problem: Using docker toolbox, only the main user directory is shared with the vm.

https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/2738

You need to place your source code inside your user directory

C:\Users\ in windows environment
\Home\ in a linux environment